# How to Load Native libraries in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, native, libraries

on this command
`hadoop checknative -a`

output is :

```
16/09/11 09:03:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable  
Native library checking:
hadoop:  false 
zlib:    false 
snappy:  false 
lz4:     false 
bzip2:   false 
openssl: false 
16/09/11 09:03:15 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide available at official hadoop website: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html

> It is fairly easy to use the native hadoop library:
>
> 1. Review the components.
> 2. Review the supported platforms.
> 3. Either download a hadoop release, which will include a pre-built version of the native hadoop library, or build your own version of the native hadoop library. Whether you download or build, the name for the library is the same: libhadoop.so
> 4. Install the compression codec development packages (>zlib-1.2, >gzip-1.2): + If you download the library, install one or more development packages - whichever compression codecs you want to use with your deployment. + If you build the library, it is mandatory to install both development packages.
> 5. Check the runtime log files.